# Error:param @param is always null

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

I have a problem with Jersey and Grizzly. The problem could be very basic but I am struggling to solve it. The idea is that I am creating an exercise application that needs to store books. Everything seems to be alright but it does not work as expected. Here is the source code:

```
@Path("/books")
public class BooksResource 
{

    private BookDao bookDao= new BookDao();

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Collection<Book> getBooks()
    {
        return (bookDao.getBooks());
    }

    @Path("/{id}")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Book getBook(@PathParam("id")String id)
    {
        Book book = bookDao.getBook(id);
        return (book);
    }
```

As can be observed, the path /books is working perfectly but the problem is that id is always null and it shouldn't be. Does anyone know where the problem comes from?

Comment: What url are you using ? Also you dont need extra "/"in your path where you expect id.

Comment: Local host, but it was demonstrated like this in the tutorial.

Comment: just localhost? That doesnt help. If you need help please provide exact url that you are using.. FYI.. it would be of form http://<host>:<port>/<bla blah>/books/<blah blah>

Comment: Here it is: http://localhost:8080/myapp/books/1234 and the id 1234 does not work. If it is only http://localhost:8080/myapp/books it is working perfectly.

Comment: did you removed "/"? if not then try it by restarting your webapp and war if any you are creating.

Comment: Yes and it is working. Thank you very much for everything. I was dealing with restful services forgot how it was. And unfortunately there was an error in the tutorial I was watching. Thank you once again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing "/" from the path and it should work.

From

```
@Path("/{id}")
```

To

```
@Path("{id}")
```

Comment: And why? My services works well with `/`, the question is therefor: why is it problem here?